# Not able to get opening hours from Google Place Details API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to get opening_hours after getting the place IDs of many stores from the Google place details API. I do not get any opening hours in the response while all of these places do show opening hours when I google them directly. For eg. this is Safeway, 1071 El Camino Real, Redwood City, CA 94063, United States.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJcY3Ya62jj4ARtl86jFsjUYE&fields=opening_hours&key=*******************
```

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {},
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like place id `ChIJcY3Ya62jj4ARtl86jFsjUYE` is of type `subpremise`, not `establishment`, so that's why you're not getting its `opening_hours` (as there are none). The place id of the establishment appears to be `ChIJpwPigbKjj4ARC4XRyMdMzJ8`.

Try this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJpwPigbKjj4ARC4XRyMdMzJ8&fields=opening_hours&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Output:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : false,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Tuesday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Wednesday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Thursday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Friday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Saturday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
            "Sunday: 6:00 AM – 10:00 PM"
         ]
      }
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Hope this helps!